# After creating a user with email and password with Android Firebase I cannot save additional information in a users collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

After creating a user using the firebaseAuth function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email, password)` I am trying to save additional information of the users that are registered in a collection called "users". For that I use `DocumentReference:`

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                FirebaseUser fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String idUser = fuser.getUid();
                DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(fuser.getUid());
                Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                Log.d("data", "username: "+username + " telef: "+telefono);
                user.put("username", username);
                user.put("telefono", telefono);
                         documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "User profile created");
                            }

                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "can´t create profile: "+e.toString());
                            }
                        });
                //sign out the user.. dont work.. any ideas?
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                mProgressBar.dismiss();
                //send the user to log in
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                RegisterActivity.this.finish();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered ok!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "can´t register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Apart from having instantiated:

```
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

I have also been forced to add the following:

```
private void initFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    }
```

Not even with the latter it works. Only the user with email and password is registered. The strange thing is that there is no error, it seems that the `onSuccess` or `onFailure` event does not occur. The database rules in the firebase console are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically this rule indicates that the user must be authenticated to be able to read / write to the database. My dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
```

I should use firebase-firestore and firebase-auth but I have added firebase-database and firebase-storage in order to solve the problem but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is signing out the user before the database is written, so the write will fail any database rules that require the user to be signed in.

`documentReference.set(user)` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before any work has been done.  The database will be written some time later.  Meanwhile, your code goes on to immediately execute a signout with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`, which deletes the user's auth token, making the query happen without any credentials.

If you need the user to be signed out after writing the database, you should do that **inside** the database callback code.  Though it's entirely clear to me why you would want that to happen.  You should probably just remove the signout completely.

Comment: Thanks @Doug Stevenson you have reason, finally it worked according your recommendation. Basically after the user make his registration I want that it goes to Log In. I have added `addOnCompleteListener` to the documentReference.set(user).. and inside it I called signOut() however the signOut don't happen..In the loginActivity.class I have this condition `if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){` I redirect the user to MainActivitiy and this is happening..now I don't know why the user is !=null if I did `signOut()`. After the registration the user should keep in loginActivity.class.AnyIdea?

Comment: I have added the Intent inside the addOnCompleteListener this fixed my problem temporarily. https://imgur.com/a/QLRpeoN